# What is the best way to manage and protect my project

Tags: c#, project

I have recently hired a new software engineer who is located overseas. I am located in America.

The project will need to be finished in Visual Studio and is created in c#.

The employee has signed an undertaking that they will keep the project confidential and that they would not disclose it to a third party and etc.

My question is, given that the employee is overseas, what is the best way to manage the project? Are there any third party applications that can assist?

Should I get the employee to create it in components or should I send him the whole MVC file?

I have looked at compiling the file but it can always be reversed engineered. I like to have a transparent and open and professional relationship with the employee so that he knows that I can trust him but also need direct control.

Comment: Do you use some source control utility?

Comment: At the moment, nothing. I am completely new to managing a project

Comment: You can let him make an VPN connection, and that the data is stored on your server... Thats the best i can think of...

Comment: Mate, everything works on a mutual understanding. You need to trust him , so will he. I wish your project will be successfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself a source control utility and start from there. If you have the funds you can look into something like Microsoft 'Team Foundation Server' which you can run in the Azure cloud for relatively little (compared to buying your own on-site server).

Otherwise consider something like a private Github account.

If he's doing his job properly he'll be making regular checkins (at least once a day, *at least*) with good comments, which means at any given moment you can just look at the version control history and see what he's checked in that day - which can give you peace of mind.

An advantage of using Team Foundation Server (TFS) is that it comes with great project management tools, you as the business owner can create work items and tasks, he can assign estimates against them and then if you use currently popular software/project management techniques you can assign those tasks to discrete iterations ('sprints') and set him goals in 2-4 week chunks. Take a read about [Scrum Method here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29).

I'm not saying there aren't other good project management tools out there (like JIRA) but TFS is the one i have most experience with, and it's also made by Microsoft.

What I think you need is a good project management framework, and software already has a lot of those so don't reinvent the wheel. As a good developer he should appreciate the value of being managed by a good agile method and more importantly it's going to let you be accountable to the business/your bosses throughout.

Comment: Thank you Henri. I have Team Foundation Server now and it is all setup correctly using the instructions on the Microsoft website.

Comment: Another question, it it possible to alter permissions in Team Foundation Server that denies a Team Project Contributor from downloading or backing up the project locally to their computer? 

Also, could you recommend any other security provisions I could implement to better make the project more safe? You have to have trust with your employees but I see the need to minimise risk if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the aspect of the trust issue (which is outwith the scope of any answers we can give here), there are probably two things you should do:

(1) Most important: Use a Source Control system. If you do not have Visual Studio Team System (and I suspect you do not), you can use a free one. There are several available, but I recommend [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) and [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). Other folks might like to recommend other ones.

(2) In order for the programmer to have access to your Source Control system, you should set them up a VPN account. How to do so is outside the scope of this answer.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use VPN you could set up a Google account and use Google Drive to share the data. It's possible to [set up GIT to work with Google Drive](http://www.iexplain.org/using-git-with-google-drive-a-tutorial/).

You can also [use RiouxSVN for free Subversion hosting](http://riouxsvn.com/).

Other than that, ensure that you can precisely specify what you need, and keep an eye on the checkins!